# Symfony 3 and Mailhog: mails not being cached by mailhog

Tags: php, symfony, email, development-environment

In my dev enviroment I want to use mailhog to catch the emails. I've installed and configure my php.ini to sustitute the sendmail property. 
If in command line i run this

```
php -r "mail(......);"
```

the mail gets captured by mailhog. The problem is with Symfony and Swiftmailer. To make a test i created a very simple controller with this:

```
/**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function homeAction() : Response
    {
        mail('some@mail.com', 'tasest', 'aaaa');
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
            ->setBody(
                'aaaaa',
                'text/html'
            );
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        return $this->render('::base.html.twig');
    }
```

Now, the email sent by the mail function gets captured by mailhog. But not the mail sent by SwiftMailer.

In my config_dev I have this:

```
    # Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "sendmail"
```

which I think should be enough.

Am I missing something here?

P.S.: If i use a real address (instead of recipient@example.com) the email gets sent and received

Update:
I also tried to configure mailhog for smtp, parameters.yml:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_port: 1025
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
```

config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    port:      "%mailer_port%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

But the result was the same result.

Comment: problem solved, a problem with the cache

Comment: Could you explain more what the problem with the cache was? I'm facing the same issue and flushing the cache doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

Comment: I remove: ```spool: { type: memory }``` and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swiftmailer setup in Symfony will usually have a more complete configuration, particularly in config_dev.yml, to be explicit of where you would send it.

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    port:      "%mailer_port%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
```

Here, if Mailhog was on port 1025 (very typical), then parameters.yml in a development environment would be set like this, to fill in the parameters in the .yml file:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_port: 1025
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with **Symfony 4**.
If you delete the variable `url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'` in `config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml`, it should work.

Comment: This didn't work in my case. I needed to keep the env MAILER_URL and add this to the `.env` file. `MAILER_URL=smtp://127.0.0.1:1025`